# LaTeX error when trying to produce PDF in R using TinyTex

Tags: r, latex, rstudio

I am trying to produce a PDF written in LaTeX using an Rnw file.

The Rnw file is trying to attach documents as a link, which requires the use of the LaTeX package **attachfile2** which I have downloaded and stored in my Latex directory to where it is sourcing all the packages.

when I click **compile PDF** in Rstudio, i achieve the following error message:

> Compiling document with tinytex ... failed   Error:
> attachfile2.sty:371: LaTeX Error: File `atfi-pdftex.def' not found.
> Error: attachfile2.sty:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file
> produced!
> [Compile PDF Stopped]

I can confirm i have the correct attachfile2.sty file, so unsure why it is referencing atfi-pdftex.def file?

Comment: The `atfi-*.def` files are part of the attachfile2 package. You have to install them as well (or let your tex distribution install the complete package instead of manually downloading individual files)